# If chess is deterministic, can we prove that from a set of infinitely large number of games, that white always wins/doesn't win?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, solution-verification, combinatorial-proofs

In some lesser complex games such as Tic-tac-toe or connect4, the first person can force a win/draw. Can we prove the same in a much more complex game like chess, where white can force a win/draw?.

Comment: We know that with perfect play, either White must win or Black must win, or the result is a draw, but the at the present time, the computation of which of these alternatives holds seems out of reach.  https://en.chessbase.com/post/500-billion-billion-moves-later-computers-solve-checkers

Comment: It depends what you mean by "can." Certainly we know in principle how to determine whether chess with perfect play is a white win, a black win, or a draw: simply "check the game tree" (since the relevant game tree is [finite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifty-move_rule), this is something we can in principle do in finite time). But the game tree for chess is far too large to actually carry this out practically. Currently no way around this is known.

Comment: To prove that, for instance, a tie is always "possible" (which I mean black can _always_ at least force a tie, never a loss, given the "correct" moves), you'd have to show that for every possible state of the board there exists a move by black, such that for all moves (afterwards) for white would cause an eventual tie (or win for black possibly). Honestly, I doubt this sort of theorem is correct or exists. I mean, as an example, when you have someone beat, you generally do so because you have forced your opponent into a finite set of possible moves, all of which result in checkmate.

Comment: Note that while the outcome of chess with perfect play on both sides is not known, it **is** known that [checkers is a draw](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/231216842_Checkers_Is_Solved/link/0fcfd50ca1d4005e6e000000/download) with perfect play on both sides. It’s by no means as complicated as chess, but it’s highly non-trivial.

Comment: Over the last 30 some odd years, chess endgame tablebases have grown from 5 man tablebases, to 6 man, to 7 man to 8 man tablebases.  What you are referring to analogizes to a 32 man endgame tablebase.